# How do I configure the default ZendLog factory for a Zend Framework MVC app?

Tags: zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3, zend-log

I have a [ZendFramework application](https://github.com/zippy1981/ZendMvcLoggingExample). Its running Zend Framework 3. I added zend-log, and injected it into the [constructor of the IndexController](https://github.com/zippy1981/ZendMvcLoggingExample/blob/master/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php#L22) I log a message in the index action of the index controller like so.

```
public function __construct(Logger $logger) 
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->logger->info('Example Log Message');
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

I was able to generate a factory for this with `vendor/bin/generate-factory-for-class`.  I added it to the module config like so.

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

When I run the index controller I get the following error:

```
/var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-log/src/Logger.php:434
No log writer specified
```

I know I can add a writer with the following:

```
$logger->addWriter($writer);
```

My question is where is the logger suppoed to be configured? Do I just add it to the `['service_manager' => 'factories' => [ . . . ] ]` in the module config?  Where should I put the factory class I write? In with the other services?

I'm struggling to solve this the "right" way.

Comment: Are you create Logger Factory? Can you paste factories for controller and logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, logger config is kept in `module.config.php`. But surelly, it can be situated elsewhere. There is no right way, but not knowing what you are trying to achieve, I'd suggest you follow the tradition.

Add to your `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'log' => \Zend\Log\LoggerServiceFactory::class,
    ],
],

'log' => [
    'writers' => [
        [
            'name' => 'stream',
            'options' => [
                'stream' => "test.log"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Your controller factory might look like this:

```
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke (ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $indexController = new IndexController();
        $indexController->setLogger ($container->get ('log'));

        return $indexController;
    }
}
```

and the controller itself:

```
use Zend\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function testAction ()
    {
        $this->logger->info("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I want.